# How to lookup multiple values based on multiple criteria in one cell?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet where I have used `SEARCH()` to get the possible linked ingredients from a match in a string. This sometimes leaves me with multiple possible matches.
Now I would like to lookup the translated words of these possible matches using an `INDEX MATCH`. Except I cannot as cells have multiple values and therefore multiple criteria.

My question is: how can I lookup multiple values based on multiple criteria and have them in one cell?

An example as better explanation:

The table I have:

| **description** | **productNameEN** | **productNameIS** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red onion | Onion, Red onion |  |
| Egg yolk | Egg, Egg yolk |  |
| Lemon | Lemon |  |

And then I would like to fill the `productNameIS` column with the translations from another table, so that it looks like this:

| **description** | **productNameEN** | **productNameIS** |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Red onion | Onion, Red onion | Laukur, Rauðlaukur |
| Egg yolk | Egg, Egg yolk | Egg, Eggjarauða |
| Lemon | Lemon | Sítronu |

This is a table example of the translations.

| **EN** | **IS** |
| --- | --- |
| Egg | Egg |
| Egg yolk | Eggjarauða |
| Lemon | Sítronu |
| Onion | Laukur |
| Red onion | Rauðlaukur |

Now the `INDEX MATCH` works for the word lemon as this is singular, but not for the other cells. I need to keep the multiple values in one cell for further use in my spreadsheet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option:

[image]

Formula in `C2`:

```
=MAP(B2:B4,LAMBDA(a,TEXTJOIN(", ",,VLOOKUP(TEXTSPLIT(a,", "),F2:G6,2,0))))
```

Comment: I get a SPILL error when I use this. I take it the `a` is just an `a` and not referencing something?

Comment: Exactly, and `SPILL#` probably means you have data in the cells below `C2`? @GT1992

Comment: I feel like an idiot! This worked perfectly thank you

Comment: No need to feel like an idiot, we all start somewhere and I'm sure you've learned something :)

Answer (score 1):

You may try `SEARCH()` with `FILTER()` then `TEXTJOIN()`.

```
=TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($I$2:$I$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($H$2:$H$6,B2))))
```

For dynamic spill array try-

```
=BYROW(B2:B4,LAMBDA(x,TEXTJOIN(", ",TRUE,FILTER($I$2:$I$6,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($H$2:$H$6,x))))))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this also works. However @JvdV was a bit quicker.